# Create a partially-filled formatted journal-book with floats and underlines

Tags: templates, blank-page, journal

Well, I realized my Tex layout skills aren't as good as my HTML skills, so I've made a web-page showing what I'm hoping to accomplish. In a nutshell, I'm making a "service journal" about people (for planning birthday gifts, etc) that will feature a small picture, name, birthdate, some information on the right-hand side, and a lined area for notes. This is a gift, so there will be maybe 10 filled-out pages resembling the image/link here, and then an arbitrary number of blanks. On the blanks, there will be a place-holder box for the picture, and all lined areas and the name and birthdate will be empty (except for the lines themselves). Once I have the template finished I can just do a for-loop including the template for the blank pages.

How can I create this, especially the three-part top area (portrait, name/bday, right-info) and a left-floating, lined main-content area? And how can I have a few filled out and the rest blanks?

Note that I do not want/need page numbers or anything else; essentially just what you see (filled out) and a blank version with lines and place-holders.

http://www.toryanderson.com/files/sample/index.html
[image: sample page]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Is this your gift or ours?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast and simple example of your layout:

[image]

The basic concept is to use three `minipages` side by side, 30% of the width each, with `\hfill` to create the gaps in between.

Personally I think you should consider a completely different layout, however; this has a lot of gaps and I think better decisions about the hierarchy of information you're displaying would go far to improve it. It looks like someone ported a web layout to a document; what works in the browser doesn't necessarily work on a printed page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \ \vspace*{-.3\baselineskip}\\
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{me.jpg}
    \end{minipage} \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{-.3\baselineskip}
            \Large \textbf{A Dear Person}\\
            1 January, 1970
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage} \hfill
    \Fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        \footnotesize
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        \textbf{Needs \& Wants:}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Ramen Noodles
        \item Facebook Time
        \item Nutella
        \item Stationary
        \item Hair-care products
        \end{enumerate}
        \textbf{Strengths-That-Are:}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Kindness
        \item Patience with People
        \item Discernment of Abilities
        \item Loyalty
        \item Empathy
        \end{enumerate}
        \textbf{Strengths-To-Be:}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Self-confidence
        \item Stress management
        \item Time management
        \item Money management
        \end{enumerate}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \end{minipage}}\\
    Lined area for writing\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
\end{document}
```